# Enlarge image canvas to compensate for blur

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have an image that I am processing with imagemagick to add a blur:

```
convert input.png -blur 0x16 output.png
```

However the blur is cropped as it goes outside the frame of the image. How can I compensate for this and enlarge the canvas to allow the blue to be fully shown?

Example image [here](http://johnlewis.scene7.com/is/image/JohnLewis/233226436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you have linked is a JPEG, not a PNG, like your command suggests, so I have no idea if it has transparency, or whether it is supposed to have lots of spare canvas around the image of the TV. As such, I am guessing what you want.

You can extend the canvas out from the centre by specifying `-gravity center` and using `-extent` so that you have space for the blur like this:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity center -extent 120%x120% -blur 0x16 output.jpg
```

However, that introduces more canvas than you need, so you may want to trim it afterwards, like this:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity center -extent 120%x120% -blur 0x16 -trim output.png
```

As an alternative, you could add some white border (I chose 500 px all round) like this:

```
convert image.jpg -bordercolor white -border 500x500 -blur 0x16 output.png
```

and remove however much you wanted to afterwards with `-shave` like this:

```
convert image.jpg -bordercolor white -border 500x500 -blur 0x16 -shave 400x400 output.png
```